# Pandas efficiency issue with tolist

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
>>> df
             speed       acc                ids  row_id
0.0       0.009766  0.004053            89806.0  8819.0
1.0       0.009766  0.001790            89886.0  8818.0
2.0       0.009766  0.000006            89886.0  8834.0
3.0       0.009766  0.003188            89886.0  8835.0
4.0       0.009766  0.007101            89806.0  8836.0
...            ...       ...                ...     ...
332659.0  8.271179  0.073181            89876.0  1816.0
332660.0  8.273315  0.297774            89876.0  1813.0
332661.0  8.282776  0.130999            89876.0  1815.0
332662.0  8.285522  0.208244            89876.0  1814.0
332663.0  8.291321  0.000395            89876.0  1822.0
```

i.e. 300k - 400k rows.
I need to create a list of each row grouped by the `ids` field:

```
out = [[[0.009766, 0.004053, 89806.0, 8819.0], [0.009766,0.007101,89806.0,8836.0]] , [[0.009766,0.001790,89886.0,8818.0], [0.009766,0.000006,89886.0,8834.0], [0.009766,0.003188,89886.0,8835.0]], ....]
```

I made it in this way and it works:

```
[v.values.tolist() for k, v in df.groupby("ids")]
```

Unfortunately this operation takes a lot of time ( almost 40 / 50 seconds! I need to do it in 15 / 20 s)
Is there any more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Does it need to be a list? The call to `tolist` incurs a copy, and numpy arrays can do everything a python list can.

Comment: No, it can also be a numpy array

Comment: Ok, then just try `[v.values for k, v in df.groupby("ids")]`. Crudely l'd guess that gives you a 2x speedup; for anything more you'd need to find a way to avoid the copying inherent in `groupby` and l'm not sure there's anything you can do towards that that doesn't take more time

Comment: Your ids are floats so grouping them is dangerous because there is no guarantee for large integers to be precise (they can be rounded resulting in wrong groups) and computing ids can result in inaccurate result that could potentially cause grouping issues later. Besides, I expect float grouping to be pretty slow compared to integers. What about converting the IDs to integers? If you can please consider using 16-bit integer or possibly 32-bit ones. Generally, the shorter the better for performance. How many unique IDs there is in the dataframe?

Comment: Could you provide full reproducible example?

Comment: If I use `[v.values for k, v in df.groupby("ids")]` as suggested from @Elliot , the computation speed up 5 / 6 times. That's great!